How to add Column Filter for time or duration in primeng table in angular
I'm using primeng's p-table in angular and i want to add a column filter to filter time/duration, but i just found date or datetime, no precise solution.
<p-columnFilter type="date" [field]="col.field" display="menu">

I'm not getting an exact time/duration column filter.

Could you create a stackblitz with the data to know what is the data and setup you are working with.

Can you please try creating a custom filter? Something like below:
component.ts

The customDurationFilter function takes two arguments: value (the cell value) and filter (the filter value).
It splits both the value and filter strings into parts (hours, minutes, seconds) and compares them. If all parts match, it returns true; otherwise, it returns false.



import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-table',
  templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.css']
})
export class MyTableComponent {
  data: any[] = [
    { duration: '00:04:53' },
    { duration: '00:03:20' },
    // Add more data here
  ];

  customDurationFilter(value: string, filter: string): boolean {
    if (!filter) {
      return true;
    }
    const filterParts = filter.split(':').map(part => parseInt(part, 10));
    const valueParts = value.split(':').map(part => parseInt(part, 10));

    for (let i = 0; i < filterParts.length; i++) {
      if (filterParts[i] !== valueParts[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}



Replace data with your table datasource. And then, in
component.html

Use the p-columnFilter component with type="custom" and filterFunction set to the custom filter function.
The matchMode is set to 'custom' to indicate that a custom filter function is being used.



<p-table [value]="data">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th pSortableColumn="duration">
        Duration
        <p-columnFilter type="custom" [field]="'duration'" [matchMode]="'custom'" [filterFunction]="customDurationFilter" display="menu"></p-columnFilter>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ rowData.duration }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>



